# sbt error when forking is enabled

Tags: scala, sbt

Sbt produce an error when there is this line:

`fork in run := true`

in this [build.scala](https://code.google.com/p/scalafx/source/browse/project/build.scala) file

The surrounding build.scala content

```
  lazy val scalafxDemos = Project(
    id = "scalafx-demos",
    base = file("scalafx-demos"),
    settings = scalafxSettings ++ Seq(
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        scalatest % "test",
        junit % "test"),
      unmanagedListing,
      description := "The ScalaFX demonstrations",
      fork in run := true,
      fork in Test := true,
      parallelExecution in Test := false,
      // print junit-style XML for CI
      testOptions in Test <+= (target in Test) map {
        t => Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-u", "%s" format (t / "junitxmldir"))
      },
```

The error produced:

```
[error] /Users/hanxue/Github/scalafx/project/build.scala:113: overloaded method value in with alternatives:
[error]   (scope: sbt.Scope)sbt.SettingKey[Boolean] <and>
[error]   (c: sbt.ConfigKey)sbt.SettingKey[Boolean] <and>
[error]   (t: sbt.Scoped)sbt.SettingKey[Boolean] <and>
[error]   (p: sbt.Reference)sbt.SettingKey[Boolean]
[error]  cannot be applied to (run.type)
[error]       fork in run := true,
[error]            ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

I can avoid the error by changing the line to `fork := true`, though that does satisfy the intent of forking only in `run` and `Test`. How can I fix this without forcing everything else to be forked?

Comment: Typically, that means `run` is coming from somewhere else.  You might try an explicit `Keys.run` to see if this is the case.

Comment: Thank you, @MarkHarrah Perhaps you might want to write an Answer below so that I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That probably means `run` is coming from somewhere else. You might try an explicit `Keys.run` to see if this is the case.